# Set prefix to Bold and preserve underline

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, rtf

I am trying to set my title to Bold and also preserve the underline. For example:

[image: TitleScreenshot]

The code keeps making all lines bold.  As you can see from the image above, only the title should be bold.  How can I fix the code to match the image?

```
        List<string> titles = new List<string> { "Basic Metabolic Panel", "Complete Blood Count", "Comprehensive Metabolic Panel" };
        List<string> bodies = new List<string> { " : Collected: 8/20/2012 5:45:00 PM", " : Collected: 8/20/2012 5:45:00 PM", " : Collected: 8/17/2012 4:18:00 AM" };


        for (int i = 0; i < titles.Count; i++)
        {
            string labName = titles[i];
            string collectionDate = bodies[i];
            int oldTextEndPoint = rtb.Text.Length;

            rtb.Text += labName + collectionDate + Environment.NewLine;

            rtb.Select(oldTextEndPoint, labName.Length + collectionDate.Length);
            rtb.SelectionFont = new Font(rtb.Font, rtb.SelectionFont.Style | FontStyle.Underline);

            rtb.Select(oldTextEndPoint, labName.Length);
            rtb.SelectionFont = new Font(rtb.Font, rtb.SelectionFont.Style | FontStyle.Bold);
        }
```

Comment: would it not be better to construct your font objects out of the loop? It looks like you're never trying to remove the bold flag?

Comment: @RowlandShaw - I shouldn't need to remove flags.  `rtb.SelectionFont.Style` work's in tandem with `RichTextBox.Select()` parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed

`rtb.Text += labName + collectionDate + Environment.NewLine;`

to

`rtb.AppendText(labName + collectionDate + Environment.NewLine);`

and things work correctly...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your are setting the SelectionFont to a new font based off of the default font of the RTB -- not based on the current SelectionFont.

Try changing it to:

```
rtb.Select(oldTextEndPoint, labName.Length + collectionDate.Length);
rtb.SelectionFont = new Font(rtb.SelectionFont, rtb.SelectionFont.Style | FontStyle.Underline);

rtb.Select(oldTextEndPoint, labName.Length);
rtb.SelectionFont = new Font(rtb.SelectionFont, rtb.SelectionFont.Style | FontStyle.Bold);
```

EDIT 1:

I just created a simple Windows Application with the following code and it does both bold and underline:

```
rtb.Text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
rtb.Select(3, 10);
rtb.SelectionFont = new Font(rtb.SelectionFont, rtb.SelectionFont.Style | FontStyle.Bold);
rtb.Select(3, 5);
rtb.SelectionFont = new Font(rtb.SelectionFont, rtb.SelectionFont.Style | FontStyle.Underline);
```

Comment: It's important to use the original code to produce equivalent results.  I also found that the first iteration works.  It's the latter iterations that break.  Because the edit only goes through a single iteration, it is an oversimplification that does not reproduce the issue any longer.  Try the original code and you should find that this solution does not work.

Comment: Yep, you are right.  After changing rtb.Font to rtb.SelectionFont and trying P.Brian.Mackey's suggestion below (changing .Text+=... to .AppendText(...)) it worked as you intended.